# error: cannot find symbol variable xml for Google analytics global_tracker

Tags: android

I am trying to implement google analytics for one of my android apps.When trying to compile their code, I am getting the error pointing the analytics application java file, mAnlTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);

Answer (score 0):

According to the developer guide quoted [here,](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4#create-global_tracker.xml)

> Note: The Firebase SDK is the recommended method to track Android apps. You can also use Tag Manager + Firebase to track them. If you choose to use Google Analytics Services SDK for Android, continue with this guide. For more information on methods to track Android apps, see Measurement options for mobile apps.

You have to add a global_tracker file in xml directory, in **res->xml->global_tracker**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <string name="ga_trackingId" translatable="false">replace with id</string>

</resources>
```

**Reference:**

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4

Comment: From where i can get ga_trackingId

Comment: In your analytics settings.. Actually google analytics is deprecated and now Firebase analytics is recommended. I don't see why you want to use this unless you have already been using it.

Comment: i already used it, now i changed my package name, so i am trying to create new account in Google analytics to integrate new google-services.json with new package name.

Comment: Create a new project and link them. Use Tools->Firebase from android studio to set up.

Comment: I don't want to change the already written code related to Google Analytics, is there any alternate way to do this

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042508?hl=en. Maybe this can help you..